# Julia has some import exception mechanism?

Tags: exception, julia

In Python we can do:

```py
try:
    import foo
    # do stuff
except ImportError:
    print("Consider installing package 'foo' for full functionality.")
```

Is it possible to catch a similar exception in Julia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this time Julia doesn't have an import exception mechanism, and you can't put `using` inside a try-catch block.

In the comments on this answer, the question is refined to really ask how to do conditional includes. Here is an example of how to do that:

```
# We are making a module that conditionally includes ImageView
module MyModule
    # Optional plotting features using ImageView
    # The view function is defined in ImageView
    export view  # Re-export ImageView.view (optional)
    try
        require("ImageView")  # Will throw error if ImageView not installed
        global view(args...) = Main.ImageView.view(args...)
    catch
        # Needs global to put it in the module scope, not the catch scope
        global view(args...) = error("ImageView.jl required for drawing!")
        # Alternatively, global view(args...) = nothing
    end
    # ....
end
```

Comment: Sounds like he wants a solution to the unsolved problems in [#2025](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/2025) (and linked issues)

Comment: I want to present some images to the user with [ImageView](https://github.com/timholy/ImageView.jl), but I do not want this package to be a strict requirement. If it's not installed in the client, then the code sections dedicated to image presentation (e.g. `view()`) should be ignored.

Comment: @IainDunning, thank you for the edit, I'll experiment with it.

Comment: @IainDunning, please see the updated question. How do I fix that first attempt?

Comment: @IainDunning, I guess you did not understand. The `view()` function is part of `ImageView`. I want to do `using ImageView: view` and fallback to `view(...) = nothing` if the package is not available.

Comment: Oh. Isn't that pretty much my original answer? I'll make it more explicit.

Comment: @IainDunning, ok, I've fixed your last edition, it was missing a `global` inside the `try` part too. Could you please update the answer so that I can accept it? We want `try require("ImageView"); global view = ImageView.view; catch global view(args...;kargs...) = nothing; end`

Comment: Done, added the global

Comment: @IainDunning, I'm accepting your answer, but to be totally correct, the catch part should be `view(args...;kargs...) = (nothing, nothing)` otherwise it will fail in the callee site `cimg, simg = view(img)`. For sure Julia needs a better mechanism for optional imports. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about ImageView. Conditional module includes will be in Julia 0.4

Comment: @IainDunning, could you please update the answer, we actually need `try require("ImageView"); global view = Main.ImageView.view; catch global view(args...; kargs...) = (nothing, nothing); end` Note the `Main` in the binding.